Salesforce Flows recursion
I have a question I've been investigating but I don't seem to come to the right answer about what's the best practice.
I'm designing a record trigger flow that will run if "Checkbox A" is set on an Account to TRUE; when that happens, all the related Assets to that account should have their own "Checkbox A" set to true as well, also all the child accounts (if it has) should have their own "Checkbox A" set to true as well as thei own related Assets.
The opposite shoudl happen as well, if the checkbox is de-selected, the same operation should run to update all the Accounts and Assets.
You may have already seen my problem here, since, even if I retrieve all the Assets and Accounts to update in the begining and run just two update operations, those updates on Accounts would re-trigger my flow unnecesarily for Accounts that have already been updated.
Hence, I was wondering what would be the propper way to bulkify the process in flows, or perhaps if this type of automation could be better achieved on Apex with static variables and a collection of the Account that have alredy been updated in the same operation.
This is the flow I have as of now, it's just the basic update operations but as you may imagine, this is quite slow and creates multiple unnecesarry DML operations:
Please note as this is an example I didn't use the real name of the field. Thus the error you see in the field assignemnt



How do you mark child accounts Checkbox A in bulk without having any operation to change the field value for Checkbox A? For example, you fetched all Child Accounts and when you update, you are not mutating the fields at all?

Sorry, not sure I get the question, but I'm making the update to the fields in the update records element. The first element to get the child records is actually no longer necesary, I just forgot to delete it. But in the "Mark Child Accounts Checkbox A" I'm retrieving all the child Accounts and setting the Checkbox A field.

is your defined as run only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements ?  this prevents flow from re-executing on same record

Yes absolutely possible to break out from a loop. You just use a decision box inside the inner loop, when the decision results True (It might be False as well based on your logic),add an element that connects the decision outside of all the loop (Outer and Inner) and it will eventually exit from both the inner and Outer loop. In the picture below B section connects the decision to an element which is outside of the loops. If condition are not satisfied all the the loop executes number of element in outer loop X number of element in inner loop and take the path A .

Hi. Not sure if I didn't explained myself correctly, but I'm not trying to break out of any loop. My problem is that my main update operation on Accounts needs to update child accounts, which in turn will trigger the same flow again resulitng in too many queries and DML operations and I'm looking for a way to do everything in as few operations as possible to avoid hitting limits.


Instead of using triggers, you can move the operation to the UI,
such as a Visualforce page, Lightning Web Component (LWC), or a
Screen Flow, to update the checkbox from Ui and update the child records

You can also check the triggered Record old value and new value to consider for processing , which will consider a record only once until it's moved to different value

If the checkbox always inherits its value from the parent, you can use a
formula field, unless it's entirely dependent on the parent.



The question is about flows, not triggers. Please read the question thoroughly before trying to answer.

Hi mine_username. Thanks for your answer. Though as Derek points out, I'm not using apex triggers, I'm using records-triggered flows.


I think this one might be a good solution, however I would still like to know what's the way to achieve this with record-triggered flows


As I mentioned earlier, I'm working on flows, so I cannot use static variables (unless there's a similar feature flows that I don't know of, if so, please let me know)


This one wouldn't work as we want users to also have the ability to update a child Account and have all the related Assets updated)



Hi David de Leon , i think you can account for update only whose  old check box and new check box value differ like decision stating Record.prior.checkbox!=Record.checkbox

Let's a account with checkbox false updated to true then when flow are re-triggers after updating to true the record prior value and new value will be true so you can consider not include that record for further operations
